# Best practice for sending lambda expression over WCF for querying Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, lambda, linq-to-entities

My application uses Entity Framework as Data Access Layer and WCF for communication and DTO objects.

What is the best practice for sending lambda expression from client to server  in order to dynamically query the database using LINQ to Entities?

**Update:**

An example:

Assume that there are flowing classes in server application

```
// Data Access Class
public class PersonService
{
    public List<Person> GetPersons(Expression<Func<PersonDto, bool>> expression)
    {
        var persons = Db.Set<Person>();
        return persons.Where(expression).ToList();
    }
}

// WCF Class
public class PersonWcfService : IPersonWcfService
{
    public List<PersonDto> GetPersons(Expression<Func<PersonDto, bool>> expression)
    {
        var personService = new PersonService();
        return ToDtoList(personService.GetPerson(expression));
    }
}
```

The `GetPerson` method filters and returns a list of `Person` based on `expression` parameter.

The code in client application may be like this:

```
Expression<Func<PersonDto, bool>> exp = x => x.Name.Contains("John");
var personWcfService = new PersonWcfService();
var persons = personWcfService.GetPersons(exp);
```

Since we can't use lambda expression directly in WCF services, what is the beset practice for sending `expression` from client application to server through WCF services?

Comment: Can you include an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: Only OData comes close to this.